# Can't access mysql database from java application

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have an java app that connects to a database. I have some computers connected in the same router and one of them is supposed to be the server. So in its localhost I created the database with the tables. Let's say that the db is in A, with IP 192.168.0.a and the app is in computer B with IP 192.168.0.b! To access the db from B I must do something like this `jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.a:3306/dbName`, but if I do not add a user in database with host `192.168.0.b`, the app will not work. So the question is: Is there a way to tell the database to accept request from all computers without adding users manually?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to access remote MySql from Workbench?

Comment: Yes I can, the problem is only for the application.

Comment: You can grant a permission to user to connect from anywhere.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql That shouldn't happen, if you're able to access remotely from Workbench you should be able to access from Java.

Comment: what exception is being thrown in your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL uses `%` as a wildcard, so for "any host", it's enough to create an user with `%` as host:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
```

Also, after this you'll need to grant the user `'user'@'%'` rights to any databases it might need.